# Why would LINQ ToLookup perform slowly with object as key

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
var data = dc.table.ToLookup(x => new ComboObject() 
{ 
  PartnerId = x.Partner_ID, 
  CustomerId = x.Customer_ID_ 
}, 
y => y);
```

This code is creating a lookup where the Key is a "ComboObject" object, and the values are the associated results from "dc.table".

My issue is, this code isn't very performant.  When querying production data, that line takes about 10 minutes. After doing some digging today, I found that if I instead made the key a String (where I concatenated the PartnerId and CustomerId values), this code runs 99% faster.  So, the good news is.. I fixed the bug!  The bad news is.. I don't know why!

**So my question is:** Why would a String-based key perform so much better than an object-based key?

Oh, and in case you were curious, my ComboObject class looks like:

```
public struct ComboObject
{
    public string PartnerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}/{1}", PartnerId, CustomerId);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does `ComboObject` have an `IEquatable` implementation?

Comment: Note that you class is setup for reference equality so only the same objects will go in the same lookup list.  If you want equality on the 2 Ids you should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in that class.

Comment: You haven't overridden `Equals` or `GetHashCode` on `ComboObject`, so all comparisons are going to be reference comparisons. This may also produce a different (larger) result than the lookup with the string key since no comparisons will be equal. You could also try using a `Tuple<string, string>` instead of `ComboObject`?

Comment: Thanks @RobertHarvey !  No, it does not implement IEquatable..

Comment: Thanks for the tip @juharr

Comment: Thanks @RufusL !  Could this also contribute to the speed issue?

Comment: Not sure, but Tuple already implements `Equals`. I'd be interested to hear if it improves your perf

Comment: @RufusL Or replaced it with an anonymous object. Comparisons are not reference since this is a `struct`, not a `class`. See [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/performance-implications-of-default-struct-equality-in-c/).

Comment: @NetMage Ah, thanks! Good point, I did not notice that it was a `struct`

Comment: Thanks for the tips everyone.  I'll override Equals and GetHashCode and run it through my unit tests again to see if that provides a performance boost.